# Proveedor de Twitter en la clase AuthUI de Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, twitter

Hola estoy implementando la autenticación con Firebase UI en mi app.
Intento llamar al proveedor de Twitter pero estoy observando que mi clase AuthUI no contiene este proveedor, solamente contiene:

```
public static final String EMAIL_PROVIDER = "email";

/**
 * Provider identifier for Google, for use with {@link SignInIntentBuilder#setProviders}.
 */
public static final String GOOGLE_PROVIDER = "google";

/**
 * Provider identifier for Facebook, for use with {@link SignInIntentBuilder#setProviders}.
 */
public static final String FACEBOOK_PROVIDER = "facebook";
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que mi clase AuthUI implemente el proveedor de Twitter?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESUELTO: el problema estaba en la versión de la dependencia 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.1.1' anteriormente tenía la versión 0.4.1.
La 1.1.1 requiere

maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

en el gradle del proyecto